# Does the Java Native Access API locally save the native libraries for execution?

Tags: java, jna

I was just wondering if anyone knew whether the Java Native Access API will locally save the native libraries into a temporary location before or when loading and using native libraries?

Comment: I was just wondering what the purpose of the native .so files that reside in the jna.jar itself.  If the native libraries you want to execute are already available in the OS, what are the purpose of these additional native files?  If they are necessary, do they not have to be available outside the jar to be used/executed?

Comment: Typically, the native bits of JNA itself are *not* available in the OS, which is why they're bundled in the jna.jar file.

Those native bits of JNA are distinct from the native libraries you are trying to access by using JNA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Libs have to be on the OS search path and are loaded from there. The native dll (win) or so (linux etc.) however has to be placed in the search path, e.g. in the main directory of your application. It might be (don't know) that the dll is contained in the .jar, in this case it is extracted into the temp folder and linked from there.